# Combinatorial explosion of interfaces: How many is too many?

Tags: design, c++, object-oriented, interfaces, polymorphism

I'm a relative newcomer to OOP, and I'm having a bit of trouble creating good designs when it comes to interfaces.

Consider a class A with N public methods. There are a number of other classes, B, C, ..., each of which interacts with A in a different way, that is, accesses some subset (<= N) of A's methods.

The maximum degree of encapsulation is achieved by implementing an interface of A for each other class, i.e. `AInterfaceForB`, `AInterfaceForC`, etc.

However, if B, C, ... etc. also interact with A and with each other, then there will be a combinatorial explosion of interfaces (a maximum of n(n-1), to be precise), and the benefit of encapsulation becomes outweighed by a code-bloat.

**What is the best practice in this scenario?**

Is the whole idea of restricting access to a class's public functions in different ways for other different classes just silly altogether? One could imagine a language that explicitly allows for this sort of encapsulation (e.g. instead of declaring a function public, one could specify exactly which classes it is visible to); Since this is not a feature of C++, maybe it's misguided to try to do it through the back door with interaces?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interface_segregation_principle

Comment: It might also be good to know the domain. Certain domains, such as game design, are sometimes more amenable to other paradigms such as component or entity based architectures. When I have run into the types of problems you're facing now in my own programs I have usually found that I either have a poor design due to a not-so-great decomposition of parts or a different paradigm is a better fit.

Comment: You said “One could imagine a language that explicitly allows for this sort of encapsulation (eg instead of declaring a function public, one could specify exactly which classes it is visible to)” — an example is Eiffel, but don't over use this feature. Also look at design by contract, this may help you group features/methods into interfaces. One interface per client is too many. Usually you will have one interface, add interfaces when it has many roles. Eg a bus is driven (much like any large vehicle), but it also carry people, therefore 2 interfaces.

Comment: book recommendation: http://touch.ethz.ch/

Comment: "(e.g. instead of declaring a function public, one could specify exactly which classes it is visible to)" This is awful, because it runs completely counter to modular design. Good code is easy to glue together with other code to form a new whole. That aside, if you rely on immutability you don't have to be paranoid about who has access to an object. Don't count on being able to do that in C++ though, since that sort of pervasive immutability is only feasible with garbage collection. You could use reference counting, but you get worse performance and have to be careful of cycles.

Comment: @Doval Designing an immutable class in C++ is tremendously easy thanks to the superb `const`. You can return `const` references to any field and not have to worry about it being modified. There is also no need to use reference counted pointers as long as your design expresses ownership clearly.

Comment: @Dennis For simple records, sure; but good luck implementing a persistent data structure. Any operation that "mutates" the data structure must return a modified copy instead of mutating the original. Any efficient implementation will involve sharing as much of the original as possible, so there won't be any clear ownership, but you still have to make sure you don't leak memory. So there's an upper limit to how much immutability you can make use of in C++ while restricting yourself to RAII and unique ownership.

Comment: @Doval Do the new move semantics not overcome this problem?

Comment: @Dennis From what I recall of C++11 move semantics are all about seamlessly transferring ownership of some resource. The problem is that for a persistent data structure, there is no unique ownership. For example, consider an immutable linked list. Adding a new element to an existing list leaves the original list unchanged, and instead creates a new list containing the new element and a pointer to the head of the original list. Now there's two references to the original list. Pretty much any efficient implementation of an immutable collection will involve sharing.

Comment: @Doval Usually what one would mean by "immutable collection" is that the collection is mutable by no-one but the owner (much more easily done in C++ than Java). If you want a const collection of consts then that must be defined at compile time (again easier in C++). Now the only issue is if you want to somehow refer to the immutable collection members within a mutable collection and then take appropriate action when a user attempts to modify one of the immutable members. This can of course be done in C++. It can also be done in Java, but certainly no easier than in C++ as far as I can tell.

Comment: @Dennis: One of the places where GC-based frameworks shine is in alleviating ownership issues for data which are never going to change.  Object instances which can change need to have owners; those which aren't don't.  I wish language/framework designers would recognize that RAII and GC each solve some problems easily that the other can do at best awkwardly, and thus combine the two approaches.

Comment: @supercat I don't agree that immutable objects do not need ownership. If the ownership (of an mutable or immutable object) is shared then it should be shared using clear semantics. That would be a reference in GC language, or a `shared_ptr` in automatic scope language. My problem is not with either approach to memory management, but with the inability to express immutability using Java. In Java you are forced to very carefully implement a `copy-on-write` design, and getters quickly become a minefield. `const` solves so many problems and clearly expresses the intent.

Comment: @Dennis: How would you define the ownership of a `String` which, after being created in .NET or Java, has references to it stored in a variety of fields, array slots, and collections, which are for the most part unaware of each others' existence?  I agree that Java and .NET have failed to recognize the most fundamental purpose of immutability.  Immutability doesn't describe something that an object can't do, but rather something it *can*: serve as a substitute for any other immutable object whose state has ever been *directly or indirectly* observed as or known to be be equivalent.

Comment: @Dennis: Knowing the ownership of *mutable* objects is absolutely critical; IMHO Java would have been a much better language had Gosling et al. encouraged the use of Hungarian notation to distinguish between methods which return a live view of a mutable object, those which return a detached copy, and those which may do either at the implementer's convenience.  Since such information is vital, but nothing in the type system encapsulates it, Hungarian notation would have made it available where it was needed.  For *immutable* objects, however, such issues aren't important.

Comment: @supercat To your first comment, they have shared ownership. Each reference owner has as strong a claim on the objects lifetime as another. Those semantics are unfortunately enforced by the language. This is modelled in RAII as a `shared_ptr` or something like that. Your approach to immutability is interesting, though I disagree about Hungarian notation as it causes practical issues in relation to code churn. To me immutability is closely related to encapsulation and it is encapsulation that Java has real issues with. `const` references allows us to build immutability & ecapsulation together.

Comment: @Dennis: In C++, the statement `foo=bar;` requires notifying the previous thing to which `foo` held a reference that it now has one fewer reference, and notifying the thing to which `bar` held a reference that it has one more.  In C# or Java, the statement simply copies 32 or 64 bits from variable `bar` to variable `foo`.  Most C# code that uses e.g. `String` doesn't care that a variable of type `String` holds a reference to an object.  All it cares about is that given such a variable, it can either read out the contents as characters, or pass it to other code that expects a `String`.

Comment: @Dennis: Another thing to consider is that a typical modern GC will know nothing about most objects that are abandoned. The GC keeps a list of objects that are "special" in various ways, and after each GC cycle will need to inspect all such items that might have been abandoned, but if an object is abandoned and isn't on one of those lists, the memory it used to occupy will be wiped wholesale without any concern for what sorts of objects it might have formerly contained.  This is *very* different from C++ where the memory manager which needs to individually release every object's memory.

Comment: @supercat The consequences of `foo=bar;` will be different depending on the types (object/reference/pointer): if `foo` & `bar` are `shared_ptr`s then it will behave as you describe. This results in a copy either 4 bytes or 8 bytes of a memory address & a 4 byte `int`, an increment, and a decrement. The runtime process does not care what that memory address is pointing to in C++ either (the compiler does that). When the `shared_ptr` (which is an object on the stack) goes out of scope the counter is decremented. When the count reaches zero the memory is released.

Comment: @supercat The thing is that using the heap memory in C++ is highly discouraged. Most objects will be managed on the stack and will have their memory automatically cleared when the stack is out of scope. This is very simple process, and despite the fantastic GC's we have available these days, it is much quicker. The issue with this manual memory management is that it is a detail that the programmer must decide upon, but at least they get to decide. For the most part it is a non-issue. Anyways I have no real problem with GC (aside from the pauses), but only with the lack of easy encapsulation.

Comment: @Dennis: In C++, if a method needs to return something that represents an immutable sequence of up to one million integers, the from my understanding any method which is given that sequence and wants to hold onto it, it will be necessary to either make a new copy of the sequence, perform a synchronized thread-safe update of a reference-counter or other usage-tracking mechanism.  In C# or Java, the method can simply return a reference to an object which has a constructor creates an array of suitable size, puts stuff into it, and stores a reference into a private field, and a method...

Comment: ...or property to read out element N of the array, but no methods which write the array or expose a direct reference.  Code which has references to such an "immutable sequence" objects can act as though each reference *is* an *independent* immutable sequence. References to such objects may be freely shared among threads, and may be copied or destroyed without having to worry about maintaining a thread-synchronized global count of the number of references that exist.  I'd call that a pretty big win for GC.

Comment: @supercat You are mixing up immutability and ownership. In C++ if an object _owns_ the collection it can allow other to access it as a read only object by giving them const references. They would then be unable to modify the collection or the _contents_ of the collection (not easily done in Java BTW!). The benefit of GC ONLY comes into play when there is shared ownership, in which case there is no behavioural changes required for the code. In C++ you must copy or use a `shared_ptr`. This is not a big deal.

Comment: Immutability is handled a lot better in C++. If you want all of your objects to be shared and mutable Java makes that the default choice for you. C++ doesn't force your hand with either, and you don't pay the cost for shared ownership on objects that are not shared. I have to work harder in my current work to model correct ownership and immutability in Java than I had to previously in C++. Java of course has lots of pluses but I feel that not having a way to naturally say "here's a read-only reference" was a mistake. You have unmodifiable collections but you can still modify the contents.

Comment: It seldom makes sense to share mutable objects. The programmer is responsible in Java for ensuring that objects which are mutable aren't shared, and that objects which are shared aren't mutable, and the language doesn't really help with that. On the other hand, `shared_ptr` has a non-trivial cost when objects might be shared among threads (and from what I understand that cost must generally be borne even if only one thread ever actually uses the object).  Further, from what I understand, when using shared_ptr it's possible for code that tries to avoid cycles...

Comment: ...to end up creating dangling references instead. In a GC framework, there's no such thing as a dangling reference. Even if an object require deterministic cleanup and become useless once cleanup is requested, no reference to that object can ever become anything other than a reference to that object, unlike C++, where a pointer to an object that no longer exists might spontaneously turn into a pointer to some arbitrary other object.

Comment: @Dennis: [Note previous two comments]

Answer (score 7):

The point of interfaces is to allow piece of code to express what API it works with. And then allow this API to be implemented by multiple classes. In your case, instead of `AforB` or `AforC`, make it `Bneeds` and `Cneeds` interface.

What you are saying also hints that there is actually only one implementation of those interfaces in form of `A`. If there is only one implementation, then there is serious flaw in the design, because point of interface is to be able to be implemented by multiple classes. If interface limits by which class it is implemented, then it is bad interface.

Comment: So you're saying that an interface should be implemented by multiple classes, not the other way round. However, the Interface Segregation Principle (linked to by @RobertHarvey) seems to suggest otherwise (see the Xerox example): a number of interfaces that a single class (and only that class) implements. Maybe this symptomatic of a bad design in the first place?

Comment: @mga ISP doesn't suggest anything like that. I would suggest not taking ISP literary, because it is quite vague to use as a rule. There is nothing that limits number of interfaces that can be implemented by a class. Other than SRP, but which is different matter entirely.

Comment: Interfaces don't need multiple implementation, but If they don't then you don't have polymorphism.

Comment: ISP states make an interface per role: A pipe can be written to and read from, so 2 interfaces, then maybe you add latter a management interface. But you don't have one per client, if you do you have too much dependency. You have to edit the class every time you add a client.

Comment: @richard: A lot depends upon what the interfaces are for.  Some common real-world situations require double dispatch for optimal implementation (e.g. render data which may be in one of many forms into one of many file formats).  Even if it would be possible to define an intermediate format to which all data could be converted, and which could then be translated into every possible file format, there would likely be some frequently-used combinations of input and output formats where such an approach would be horribly inefficient.

Comment: @richard: Code which needs data in a particular format shouldn't be bound to the translation class, but may well require features that other formats don't have.  In such case, having the translator implement `ISuperDuperFormatDataSource` would seem the best approach.  The translator may get big and bulky, but the complexity is needed *someplace*; better to have it in a class whose rule is to take it away from other places.

Answer (score 6):

> Is the whole idea of restricting access to a class's public functions in different ways for other different classes just silly altogether?

Yes and no. Bear with me.

Restricting access to a specific class is silly. While it is important to separate a class from the implementation of its dependencies, it's arguably more important to separate a class from the details of the class dependant on it.

For this reason, it's also silly to name your interfaces as if they are a link between the two classes. They're not.

To the calling class, as Euphoric points out, the interface is "I need to be able to do this ... I don't care how it's done." The name should reflect that. ie. Rather than an interface between ProductService and SqlProductRepository called SqlProductRepositoryForProductService, there should be an interface known to the ProductService called ProductRepository ("I need to be able to save a product and I don't care how"), which is implemented by SqlRepository.

But SqlRepository may also be able to store Orders. And in this sense, it DOES make sense to limit access FROM ProductService to SqlRepository so that it can only store Products. OrderService may access the SqlRepository through a new interface called OrderRepository.

Why bother, you ask? Why not simply access the class, or an interface that gives you access to the whole class?

Because it might be that, once SqlRepository has grown beyond control, you want to break it down. Perhaps into a SqlMembershipRepository (which might handle users, groups, roles, etc) and a SqlManufacturingRepository (which might handle products, components, etc) and a SqlSalesRepository (which might handle orders, customers, etc). If you've allowed everything access to all of the SqlRepository, you might find this a much tougher task than simply breaking the class into three and implementing the same interfaces that the Services always needed. Especially true if you have several classes that need to save a product.

Or, and this may be the most important point, you might want to change the way you handle Sales only. For some reason, you might decide to store it in a file, or in a NoSql database.

If you've kept your interfaces segregated, you only need to implement the ProductRepository interface on the new NoSqlRepository. If you kept it as one interface, you would have to implement SaveOrder in the NoSqlRepository (even if it were a blank method, because it was never used) and leave the implementation of SaveProduct on SqlRepository.

Suddenly your entire abstraction between services and repositories would make no sense. Another developer may come along and write some code that will store an order. There is a very good chance that they'll accidentally call the empty SaveOrder method on the NoSqlRepository, instead of the SaveOrder method on the SqlRepository. And they may be very confused when that doesn't work.

Comment: @pdf Very good explanation, thank you. In hindsight, I think I hyperbolized my example a little, and as I am a beginner in OOP, I would be better off looking at a simpler, more concrete case. If you don't mind a follow-up question, consider this scenario: A has 2 public methods: Foo() and Bar(). B and C both act on A, but B requires both methods, while C requires only Foo(). In that case, would you implement an interface to hide Bar() from C?

Comment: @mga: Not knowing what Foo and Bar do, it's hard to say. I can think of circumstances where I'd give either answer. And circumstances where I'd derive one interface from the other, and circumstances where I wouldn't. Unfortunately, this is the kind of thing where experience will tell you what to do. Whether that be an experienced colleague, or an answer to a specific question here or on codereview, or simply taking an educated guess and learning from getting it wrong. (Which is what most of us have done at some point.)

Answer (score 1):

If B and C need different things, there's probably a need for two interfaces. If those happen to be implemented by the same class, so be it.

What strikes me here is your inter-dependency of the classes. In order to be able to refactor code at a later point your objects shouldn't depend on each other. Even if you hide it with interfaces, they shouldn't be calling each other, which seems to me to be the actual flaw here. Maybe what you actually need is some kind of facade but that's a wild guess without knowing the details.

I think you should rethink A using B and, at the same time, B using A. That's probably the root cause of your problem.

Comment: Good point on the design being flawed if all classes are using each other. In an attempt to get my point across, I overstated it. Please see the comment I put under pdr's post, with a much simpler, more concrete scenario.

Comment: @mga For what it's worth, I agree with pdr, especially with the last comment: experience will probably answer you when to split interfaces. If you want to solve the particular case here, try asking a more concrete question, as suggested. :)

Answer (score 0):

This would indicate to me that a class is too large and/or in-cohesive (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cohesion_%28computer_science%29). Otherwise you should be guided to the interface by the purpose of the class. Are you trying to do too much in a single class?

Express as small an amount of functionality as possible via the actual public interface of the class but keep it flexible.
For example: Say you have a data storage class that can process SQL. Do not put application specific "helper" methods in there. Just use a generic `get`, `put`, `update`, `delete` methods which take SQL queries. The rest (e.g. `std::vector<Record> getDepartmentRecords(const DeptId& dept)`) can be handled in wrapping classes.

The last thing is that you should not try to design explicitly for a client of your class, just put the operations on the class that most make sense for it. If some other class wants to restrict their dependencies on your class then it is up to them to decide if they want to use an intermediary interface. Personally I think this is good practise when using third party libraries but for internal dependencies it shouldn't really be necessary (beyond the normal class hierarchy interfaces of course!)